# How to submit a form through ajax in safari browser in grails

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, safari, grails-2.0

I am trying to submit a form through ajax function while button

but on **safari** browser its submitting like a normal form submitting.

and In other browser its working properly through **ajax** function

```
<g:form action="addEmpHistory" name="formNew" method="post">

 <button id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" onclick="submitform(formNew);"></button>

</g:form>
```

//Ajax code

```
function submitform(data){  
    $("#"+data).submit(function(event) {    
        new Event(event).preventDefault();
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user/addUSer',
            data: $('#'+data).serialize(),

            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();  
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please could you post your `submitform` function. I would first check that the `submitform` function is actually being called using alert(), and if it is, debug the `submitform` function.

Answer (score 1):

Seen as you are using jQuery, consider removing onclick

```
<form action="addEmpHistory" id="formNew" name="formNew" method="post">
    <button id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn">Submit</button>    
</form>
```

and replacing your submitform function with jQuery event binding, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formNew").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user/addUSer',
            data: $("#formNew").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        return false; // prevent actual form submit
    });
});
```